# Take image from XML - Steam

Tags: php, xml

i take XML table from steam - information about steam user inventory for this link: 
http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=XXXX&SteamID=XXX

EXAMPLE:

```
{
            "id": 5267945040,
            "original_id": 4985950915,
            "defindex": 9,
            "level": 1,
            "quality": 4,
            "inventory": 3221225475,
            "quantity": 1,
            "rarity": 2,
            "flag_cannot_trade": true,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "defindex": 6,
                    "value": 1116733440,
                    "float_value": 72
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 7,
                    "value": 1135152909,
                    "float_value": 338.11758422851563
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 8,
                    "value": 1052989602,
                    "float_value": 0.38153558969497681
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 75,
                    "value": 1457251200,
                    "float_value": 120885075771392
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 147,
                    "value": "models/weapons/stattrack.mdl"
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 39,
                    "value": 0,
                    "float_value": 0.38999998569488525
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 40,
                    "value": 0,
                    "float_value": 0.5
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 16,
                    "value": 1,
                    "float_value": 1.4012984643248171e-045
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 199,
                    "value": 30,
                    "float_value": 4.2038953929744512e-044
                },
                {
                    "defindex": 142,
                    "value": "models/weapons/w_snip_awp_icon.mdl"
                }
            ]

        }
```

How i can a download to array a weapon model and show it on my site..
As for this example

```
"value": "models/weapons/w_snip_awp_icon.mdl"
```

Sorry for bad english

Comment: ? That's JSON, not XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself am not too experienced with fetching XML data. I am pretty experienced with the steam API and will be glad too help you. From what I am reading you are trying to correlate the in-game view model `models/weapons/v_snip_awp_icon.mdl` with a image to show on your webpage.

Here's a little template that may help.

XML File:

```
<aaaa Version="1.0">
   <bbb>
     <cccc>
       <dddd Id="id:pass" />
       <eeee name="hearaman" age="24" />
     </cccc>
   </bbb>
</aaaa>
```

PHP Snippet: (SimpleXMLElement is a good way to grab data within PHP without getting to advanced)

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
echo $xml->bbb->cccc->eeee['name'];
echo $xml->bbb->cccc->dddd['Id'];
```

I would also recommend trying [steamanalyst.com's](http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/contact-us) api

Comment: They have a API but it is not free. You have to contact them about it. The price is undisclosed.

Comment: No problem! Feel free to contact me for further help.

Comment: I do not know the price of the API because the price is not public to developers like us. They will most likely tell you the price of the API if you email them.

Comment: So there is another method for obtaining prices of items and image items?

Comment: The only other logical way is to create a item API yourself.